# Can't get data out of Firebase Snapshot

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I've found many threads with similar questions...but I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

I have a database that stores items, and baskets. It's a practice "scan-and-go" style payment app.

My Firebase DB is structured like this:

```
Store_POC{
  "Store_SKU_List":{
    "Store_ID":{
      "Item_ID":{
        "item_name":
        "item_sku":
        "item_price":}
      }
    }
  }
 "Baskets":{
   "Store_ID":{
      "Auto_Gen_Basket_ID":{ 
        "Auto_Gen_Item_ID":{
          "item_name":
          "item_price":
          "item_sku":}
```

I am able to type in a store, and sku number and retrieve the values associated with that particular item. Here is the code I am using:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseDatabase

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

//Firebase
var ref: FIRDatabaseReference!


//Interface Elements
    //Sku Lookup
    @IBOutlet weak var textStoreId: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var textItemSku: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelItemName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelItemSku: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var labelItemPrice: UILabel!

var currentItem = [String:String]()
var currentItemModel = Item()
var activeBasket = Basket()

@IBAction func buttonAddToBasket(_ sender: UIButton) {
    activeBasket.addItem(item: currentItemModel)
}

@IBAction func buttonLookUpItem(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var itemData = [String:String]()

    self.ref?.child("Store_SKU_List").child(textStoreId.text!).child(textItemSku.text!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {

        (snapshot) in
         itemData = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
        print(snapshot)
        print(itemData)

        self.labelItemName.text = self.currentItem["item name"]
        self.labelItemSku.text = itemData["id"]
        self.labelItemPrice.text = itemData["item price"]
        self.currentItem = itemData

        self.currentItemModel.name = itemData   ["item name"]
        self.currentItemModel.sku = itemData["id"]
        self.currentItemModel.price = itemData["item price"]

    })
}
```

However - here is the first issue I am running into. I can't get the data I am pulling from firebase to be assigned to the variable **currentItem** which is declared in the main ViewController class.

I want to have the item that was just looked up stored so that it can be "added to the basket" without having to look up all the variables again.

I've seen lots of tutorials about getting and accessing firebase data, and I believed I had been following them correctly. If so, why can I not assign the retrieved values to currentItem?

This may be a separate issue...but I am mentioning it in case it's relevant.

I have tried to separate my calls to the database into functions. Instead I would call something like `getSkuInfo(sku:"123-1")` and try to do the lookup. When I did this, I can see that I am getting the values back, but the info isn't leaving the FIRDatabase call, and an empty array is sent back as the function result.

Comment: I see you have a print statement for itemData. Are you saying that the print statement shows it contains no data? Also, right now the keys you're using in the database--"item_name",  "item_sku", and "item_price"--are not the same keys you are trying to get values from in the itemData dictionary. As a result, itemData["id"] and itemData["item price"] will have a value of nil.

Comment: Actually, my print statement for snapshot and itemData do come back with values.

`Snap (123-1) {
    id = "123-1";
    "item name" = Snapple;
    "item price" = "2.99";
}`

`Table Data: ["id": "123-1", "item price": "2.99", "item name": "Snapple"]`

So...I guess my question is why it won't assign those values to the variable `current item model`?

I've been reading about how the DB is async...does this have something to do with it?

Comment: Another edit...if I look-up the same SKU twice...then everything works as expected...

Comment: Then I'd say you're right that it has to do with the fact that downloading the data is asynchronous. It sounds like you're trying to use the data before it's actually there.

Comment: Ok - I am still learning about how async works....

I had assumed that when I call a function which requests data from Firebase, the data will be returned "immediately", or, at least before the function finishes running. Is this correct?

Comment: The data will be returned when it is available. In the meantime, the program  continues executing so that users aren't stuck waiting for something to happen. Here's a tutorial that explains a bit about synchronous v asynchronous programming: https://www.raywenderlich.com/148513/grand-central-dispatch-tutorial-swift-3-part-1